# Cinnamon dual monitor icons

Tags: icons, cinnamon, multiple-monitors

I'm using **Ubuntu 17.04** with **Cinnamon 3.4.3** on a dual monitor.

I got a issue with icons on desktop. My external monitor is set has the **primary monitor** and I selected that I want see the icons only on this monitor but I see the icons in both monitors plus those on the external are just images, they are not clickable!

Any solution to fix it?

Tnx